# GridView onrowcommand confirm box

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a ButtonField in Gridview and I'm using onRowCommand to fire the action. I need a confirmation box in onRowCommand event to return/skip the codes if the user click in "Cancel"

Here is grid.aspx.cs

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string commandname = e.CommandName;

        if (commandname.Equals("atender"))
        {
              // here there are the codes...I need a confirmation box here which skip these codes if the user click in cancel

          }
       }
```

and here is the asp from my gridview

```
          <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" CellSpacing="1" Width="100%" 
            GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" PageSize="5" HorizontalAlign=Left
            >
                            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="tabela_texto2" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="tabela_texto1" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Status" CommandName="atender" ButtonType="Button" />
            <asp:ButtonField Text="Ver no mapa" CommandName="ver" ButtonType="Button" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you'll need javascript for confirm box and you must open it before there is a hit on server

Comment: How can I add this javascript in this code? Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript or Jquery to take the control in browser (client side), to make it: 

1) add an ControlStyle-CssClass to the ButtonField:

```
<asp:ButtonField ControlStyle-CssClass="botonTransaccional" Text="Status" CommandName="atender" ButtonType="Button" />
```

2) Download the JQuery library (Single JS File) from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
3) Save the file in a directory of your application (in my sample in JS Folder)
4) Add the reference in the HTML, after add the jquery functionality to control the event in client side (You can add in the Head of HTML document).

```
   <script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".botonTransaccional").click(funtion(e) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?") == false)
        {
          e.preventDefault();
        }  
      });
    });
  </script>
<br>
```

The e.PreventDefault() function prevent the Event Default of control, in a button element the Default is the PostBack o Submit to the server.

Comment: How add I the jquery in cs?

Comment: gracias! Si, yo hablo

Comment: Ok, espero que te sirva, no olvides marcar como solución a tu pregunta y votar si así lo decides.